# Android studio does not resolve classes written in Kotlin (.kt) in the IDE but compiles fine

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide, kotlin

I'm starting to work on an existing project which uses standard java and partially Kotlin for some classes.

**PROBLEM:**

The projects ***compiles and runs fine***, but when viewing the code in Android Studio, the ***classes written in kotlin show unresolved in the ide***.

---

**UserConfigActivity.kt** (Class written in Kotlin)

```
class UserConfigActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_config)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

---

**Unresolved when referenced/used in standard java class** (although compiles and runs fine):

[image]

---

When opening the `.kt` files directly in android studio it prompts that a plugin is found as follows:

[image]

But when i click on `Install Plugins`, nothing happens (no install or change in situation). Prompt reappears next time i open another `.kt` file.

---

**QUESTIONS:**

1. How to resolve the `Cannot resolve symbol` for classes written in Kotlin?
2. How to install the plugin which is offered in prompt but does not install when clicking `Install Plugins`?

I'm on `Android Studio 2.1.1`.

Comment: I'm not big expert, do you use instant run?

Comment: yes all the time, but how can that be a problem in this situation?

Comment: Did you also apply kotlin plugin in gradle?

Comment: yes `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

Comment: Then I don't know the reason and would ask in kotlin slack or jetbrains issue tracker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To install the Kotlin plugin, open the Settings dialog, select the "Plugins" node, press the "Install JetBrains plugin" button and select "Kotlin" from the list. Then restart the IDE.